# Near Resonant Behaviour

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I'm reading Landau's Mechanics and on Chapter 5 on small oscillations he says in a footnote

'The "constant" term in the phase of the oscillation also varies".

I am a bit confused as to what this means, since as far as I can tell even if the phase of the free oscillation and the force are different i.e.
$$x=Ae^{i(\omega t+\alpha)}+Be^{i[(\omega+\epsilon)t+\beta]}$$
it doesn't suddenly gain a time dependence when it is factored together in the form
$$x=\left[Ae^{i\alpha}+Be^{i(\epsilon t+\beta)}\right]e^{i\omega t}$$
the phases still seem to be time independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that Landau is referring to the content of the square bracket.

Simple harmonic motion can be written using complex exponentials as

$x(t) = X e^{i \omega t}$,

being $X$ a constant complex number. This is not the case in the presentation of Landau, since he's summing two harmonics and get the same result you wrote in your question, namely

$x(t) = \left[ A + B e^{i \varepsilon t} \right] e^{i \omega t} $,

being the content of the square brackets a function of time.

As Landau's is summing an harmonic at resonance frequency $\omega$, $Ae^{i\omega t}$, and the forced response $B e^{i(\omega + \varepsilon) t}$ with a forcing  $\omega + \varepsilon$ close to the resonance frequency, we can assume that $\varepsilon$ is small when compared with the frequency $\omega$:

- thus, the content of a square bracket can be approximately considered as constant over a short period of time, varying very slowly w.r.t. the period of the oscillation $\omega$;
- when you sum two harmonics with very close frequencies, you get the phenomenon of **beats**, namely the superposition results in a fast oscillating harmonics, modulated by a low-frequency one. This is readily checked either:

  - with what we've done using complex harmonics: summing $Ae^{i\omega t}$ and $B^{i(\omega + \varepsilon)t}$ we got $[A + Be^{i\varepsilon t}] e^{i \omega t}$, i.e. the product of a fast and slow (modulating) harmonics

  Have a look at wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)